# Should EntityManager lifetime be per Servlet Request? Or longer?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jpa, servlet-filters

I am currently obtaining an `EntityManager` from the `EntityManagerFactory` within the `doFilter` method of a servlet `Filter`, passing it to the Servlet, and closing it on the way out.

Is this good practice as far as the lifetime of `EntityManager` is concerned?  Or should I have a different lifetime for `EntityManager`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds good to me.

Filters and servlets will be used by multiple threads at once (unlike stateless or statefull EJB). So the `EntityManager` should be looked up per request.

Alternatively, you can force the web container to synchronize accesses to servlets (not sure for filters) by specifying that the `SingleThreadModel` is desired, in which case you could inject the `EntityManager` once for all in your filter or servlet.

The information above come from this post about [PersistenceContext in a web app](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ss141213/archive/2005/12/dont_use_persis.html).

Obtaining an `EntityManager` is I believe a cheap operation (unlike obtaining the factory itself). At least, that was the case with Hibernate's Session and SessionFactory. So I would go for your original design.

Comment: The article which you linked there is nice, but has a horribly misleading title. It should have been "Don't use @PersistenceContext in a Servlet".